# Java Android. Error when executing query in DatabaseHelper

Tags: java, android, string, sqlite, textview

I want to retreive from sqlite all products which have same market with one selected from a spinner

my function from databasehelper is:

```
public String getSelectedData(String market) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_PRODNAME, KEY_PRODAMOUNT ,KEY_AMOUNTTYPE, KEY_MARKETID};
    Cursor c= myDatabase.query(DATABASE_PRODTABLE, columns, KEY_MARKETID + "=" + market, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    //int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRODROWID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRODNAME);
    int iAmount = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRODAMOUNT);
    int iAmountType = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AMOUNTTYPE);
    int iMarket = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MARKETID);
    int i=0;
    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        i++;
        result = result + i + ". " + c.getString(iName) + " " + c.getString(iAmount) + " " + c.getString(iAmountType) + " " +  c.getString(iMarket) +  "\n";
    }
    return result;

}
```

It gives gives me an error when executing getSelectedData(market)

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setare continut din layout
    setContentView(R.layout.viewlist);
    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSQLinfo);
    buton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    buton.setOnClickListener(this);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String market = bundle.getString("market");

    //tv.setText("Data send from previous intent nSite Name = +" + market );
    //Afisare produse din baza de date
   DatabaseHelper info= new DatabaseHelper(ViewProductsActivity.this);
    try {
        info.open();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  String data = info.getSelectedData(market);
  tv.setText(data);
  info.close();
```

Comment: I think the problem is at : KEY_MARKETID + "=" + market but i don't know why. KEY_MARKETID  is defined at TEXT NOT NULL

Comment: If you'd post the error log as well, it would be much easier to tell what's wrong.

Comment: It doesn't get me any type of error in Eclipse. In Emulator it only says that "The application xxxx(process androidpack.namespace) has stopped unexpectedly.Please try again."

Comment: I have the same problem when executing Delete also.It doesn't execute delete query when i add a condition like KEY_MARKETID + "=" + market.

Comment: Then the problem surely shows up in LogCat in the DDMS perspective in eclipse. Typically, an unhandled Exception will be printed to the system log.

Answer (score 0):

consider declaring KEY_MARKETID as NUMERIC or as INTEGER, a word of advice is that you should always use numbers for IDs and not Strings.
here is an example:

```
private static final String BUDGETS_CREATE=
"create table budgets ("+KEY_ROWID+" integer primary key autoincrement,"
+KEY_LIST+" text not null, "+KEY_BDGT+" integer not null, "+KEY_SOLD+"numeric);";
```

here is a reference that might be helpful of the sqlite data types:
http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

another way that you could do your query is using the [raw query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) statement.
and put in a string your query.

```
String sqlwhere ="SELECT * FROM budgets;";
Cursor cur=mDb.rawQuery(sqlwhere, null);
```

Comment: Solved with this : Cursor c= myDatabase.query(DATABASE_PRODTABLE, columns, KEY_MARKETID + "=?", new String[] { market }, null, null, null, null);